# How to prevent google sign out after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I used following source code to integrate google sign.

```
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="397716624167-qkrenp3c7e81a7br3pop83e90le6eslr.apps.googleusercontent.com">


<script type="text/javascript">
                var name = undefined;
                var picture = undefined;
                var email = undefined;
                function renderButton() {

            gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
                'scope': 'profile email',
                'onsuccess': onSuccess,
                'onfailure': onFailure
                });
}
      function onSuccess(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            name  = profile.getName();
            picture = profile.getImageUrl();
            email = profile.getEmail();
            }
```

Problem is my page gets sign out after page refresh.How to prevent it from getting sign out.

Comment: You need to save your session. You can use local storage or a session on your web server. You have not provided enough information about the environment to answer.

Comment: Code is in php file.I am not getting what do you mean by environment.

Comment: Environment means where your code runs, which language, which framework all the details that matter. Google search "PHP sessions".

Comment: Another suggestion. You should be running your OAuth code at the server and not in the browser. There are exceptions but as a general rule, you will have a much easier time with development.

Comment: How to use php session to stay sign in after refresh?@JohnHanley

Comment: I have observed that, I am signining out from my web page I am still signed in to google,when I sign out of google also,my problem gets solved. I am still signed in to web page after refresh also,but I am getting  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775612/the-page-you-were-on-is-trying-to-send-you-to-http-localhost-website?noredirect=1#comment100106887_56775612. notice How to get rid of that?

Comment: Use Google search. There are lots of examples. Try a few, study how they work.