# The page you were on is trying to send you to http://localhost/website

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, google-signin

How to avoid

> The page you were on is trying to send you to http://localhost/website

this page redirection notice while logging out from google.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://localhost/website/" onclick="signOut()" style="margin-right: 10em">sign out</a>
```

I am using above code.

Comment: Try removing `?continue=http://localhost/website/` ?

Comment: I want to redirect to my previous page after log out

Comment: You will have to keep track of what that previous page was and replace ```http://localhost/website/``` with that variable data.